# Cases where HTML is not frowned upon inside of php?

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller, standards, conventions

I know that control stuff should be separated from view stuff, but there's so many cases where I know it's slower and over-complicating to do things with html templates.

My question is... where is it acceptable?

Examples of what I'm talking about... functions that output very dynamic tables, functions that create input elements, and functions that format text.

The only con I can think of, other than it being "ugly," is that I don't tab out and newline inside of these functions, which makes the output HTML a bit ugly. Most of the time when I face this, I just say forget convention - functionality wins in most cases.

Anyone have any insight or opinions on the topic to share?

Comment: Don't worry about the whitespace in HTML output (unless it's preformatted). Tools like firebug give you a well-formatted view of the dom regardless of how much extra whitespaces is in it.

Comment: I surely don't look at the HTML of the webpages I visit (unless I want to see how the good ones work), so as long as it's valid, you're fine. Just *look* at Google's homepage! It's invalid, but it's a single blob of unreadable code.

Comment: This question belongs on [Proprammers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) and should be rephrased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's more work, but the MVC pattern is much more maintainable in the long run. Even for dynamic tables, it would be better to create a class that can create any size table/list/divs and then pass your data to it than have view data in your model/controller.

I sometimes cheat a bit on very small projects and mix in business logic with presentation, but if the project ever grows it usually is more work correcting it down the road. So unless I'm being really lazy, it's not that hard to be fairly strict with implementing code in an MVC manner.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much you want to separate your concerns. The general rule is you should be able to switch out the display of your page without affecting the behind-the-scenes logic.

Think of whether what you are writing falls under the presentation layer of your site, or the business logic.

If part of what you are writing is completely separate from how it will be displayed, it should probably be in another place.

But again, this is very much up to the developer and scope of the project. For small projects, having logic intermixed with presentation (HTML) is not a bad thing as it saves time. However if you are developing a massive application, you need to be much more strict with separation of concerns to make maintenance easier in the long run.